# Nullable Int in Swift

Tags: swift, int, nullable

I am attempting to use a hash that contains a nullable int as a value. The below is the code.

```
var facs:[(pk:Int,phone:Int?,name:String)] = []
var phone: AnyObject? = fac["phone"]!
var phoneLong:Int?;
if(phone == nil){
    phoneLong = nil
}
else{
    phoneLong = phone as? Int
}
var id = fac["id"]! as Int
var name = fac["name"]! as String

facs.append(pk:id, phone:phoneLong, name:name)
```

However, I get a compile error on the `facs.append` line that states `Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'`. I've tried a few variations, and the only way I can get rid of the error is to make phone a non-nullable int, which is not what I need. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `append` method doesn't correctly detect the parameters as a tuple - just make that explicit by assigning the tuple to a variable:

```
let params = (pk:id, phone:phoneLong, name:name)
facs.append(params)
```

Comment: Wow. way to go Swift. That worked perfectly, although you'd think it should work without the explicit assignment.

Comment: It's because `facs.append(pk:id, phone:phoneLong, name:name)` is ambiguous. It looks like you're calling `append(pk:phone:name:)` (at which point the compiler's error system blows up and gives you nonsense). You can get the same fix by using double parens. (But this use of tuples is likely to cause a lot of headaches all over the place; you'd be better of building a trivial struct if you're going to use it more than once.)

Comment: Yes normally it would work, but enclosing the tuple with parenthesis, i.e. `facs.append((pk:id, phone:phoneLong, name:name))`. In your specific case I think it's failing because the parameter is of a generic type (it's an array). In the case of a non generic method/function it should work.

Comment: Noted. In this case, it's more a pass, use, forget situation. I didn't think a struct would really be necessary in this case, but I may transition if it becomes too problematic.

Comment: Yeah; you can dramatically simplify this code, especially the phone -> `phoneLong` conversion and keep it typesafe (no need for `!` or `AnyObject`, which is another big source of compiler headaches). https://gist.github.com/rnapier/f902813b9f22a3c3790e